# Function to recursively add multiple vectors element somehow gets a double as argument

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, variadic-templates

For a homework problem, we have to work with variadic templates and expression templates. To do see, they made an exercise to show the difference between what they call a "simple" and a "single-loop" sum. For this question, the "single-loop" is irrelevant; the problem I have is with the simple sum. The idea of the simple sum is that you recursively add the vectors, where two vectors are added using a for loop over each element. We are not supposed to use fold expressions. We are allowed to assume the vectors have the same length.

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename V, typename... T>
std::vector<V> add_vectors_simple(
    const std::vector<V>& head, const T&... tail)
{
    std::vector<V> result(head.size()); // DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS LINE - IT IS NECESSARY FOR SPEC TESTS.
    
    std::vector<V> tail_sum = add_vectors_simple(tail...);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = head[i] + tail_sum[i];
    };
    
    return result;
}

template<typename V> // Specialization for single argument
std::vector<V> add_vectors_simple(
    const std::vector<V>& vec)
{
    return vec;
}

std::vector<double> test_add_vectors_simple(
    const std::vector<double>& a, const std::vector<double>& b,
    const std::vector<double>& c, const std::vector<double>& d)
{
    return add_vectors_simple(a, b, c, d);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 10000;

    std::vector<double> a(n);
    std::vector<double> b(n);
    std::vector<double> c(n);
    std::vector<double> d(n);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives a compilation error, however, given by:

```
main.cpp:9:31: error: no matching function for call to 'add_vectors_simple'
    std::vector<V> tail_sum = add_vectors_simple(tail...);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'add_vectors_simple<double>' requested here
main.cpp:9:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'add_vectors_simple<double, std::vector<double>>' requested here
main.cpp:9:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'add_vectors_simple<double, std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>' requested here
main.cpp:29:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'add_vectors_simple<double, std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>' requested here
    return add_vectors_simple(a, b, c, d);
           ^
main.cpp:4:16: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at least argument 'head', but no arguments were provided
std::vector<V> add_vectors_simple(
               ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't understand why this error occurs. Does the unpacking of tail somehow peel off a double instead of a vector due to a failure in type deduction?

Edit: as @Raymond Chen pointed out in the comments, the problem is that the base case comes after the recursive case, so it will use the recursive case when it should use the base case instead. Switching the order solves the problem

Comment: You never actually said what a "simple sum" or "single loop sum" is! It's hard to understand your function without knowing what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: It isn't necessary to say what a single loop sum is, since this isn't about that, but with 'simple sum', a sum that is computed recursively is meant. So the arguments are multiple vectors, and it first sums the last two vectors, then it sums that result with the second to last and so on. The summation of two vectors should be done with a for loop over the elements. I'll try to clarify the question itself too.

Comment: Okay, this is elementwise vector sum. The problem is due two-phase lookup. Your recursive case is defined before the base case, so the compiler doesn't see the base case when expanding the recursion. When you get to `add_vectors_simple(a, b)`, it then tries to call `add_vectors_simple(b)`, which matches only the recursive case (since the base case doesn't exist yet), and then the recursive `add_vectors_simple(b)` tries to call `add_vectors_simple()`, which fails.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Not only is it required here, but it also helps you understand and perhaps fix the problem yourself. Even if not, you'd then e.g. know if adding elements or recursion are actually relevant.

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed the code so it now produces the error with what I think is the least number of code.

Comment: [It compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/7zGrGEE91) if you simply move the one-argument overload before the variadic one. Raymond Chen explained why, in the third comment.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen, I missed your comment earlier, that is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been identified in the comments, so this is **not** an answer, but one can’t create code blocks in comments… Things I would suggest:

0. <s>It doesn’t have to be recursive.</s> (EDIT: It does, apparently, because the homework assignment says so. However, the use of template recursion should be the *last resort* when an argument pack is too heterogeneous for a common fold expression, not the *default*. One *can*, of course, implement the type inference (the expression in `decltype`) and all the points below using recursion. Which is not to say one *should* do that in practice.)
1. It should always get the return type right: When `head` is a vector of `int`s and `double`s are anywhere in `tail...`, it should sum up to `double`s, not `int`s.
2. In case the numbers are non-trivial, e.g. large GNU MP numbers, it should at least try some (perfect) forwarding, just in case the input vectors are movable.
3. It should *not* insist on inputs being vectors; indexable containers of the right size should do. (This opens a nice can of worms of `map<size_t, numeric>` in `tail...` instead of a full `vector`, defaulting to zeros etc.)

```cpp
template <typename V, typename... T>
auto add_vectors_simple(V &&head, T &&...tail) {
  std::vector<decltype((head[0] + ... + tail[0]))> result;
  result.reserve(head.size());
  for (size_t i{}; i < head.size(); ++i)
    result.emplace_back(
        (std::forward<V>(head)[i] + ... + std::forward<T>(tail)[i]));
  return result;
}
```

Let‘s test it. (The last (forth) case matters most.)

```cpp
const std::vector<int> is{1, 2, 3, 4};
const std::vector<double> ds{4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5};

for (auto x : add_vectors_simple(is, is)) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

for (auto x : add_vectors_simple(ds, ds)) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

for (auto x : add_vectors_simple(ds, is)) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

for (auto x : add_vectors_simple(is, ds)) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Possible output:

```
2 4 6 8 
9 7 5 3 
5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 
5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
```

**[And here it is on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/bnq74xob3)**

Comment: "We are not supposed to use fold expressions."

Comment: @RaymondChen Yikes. I completely missed that part of the question. (Which is too absurd to make any sense.) My points other than `0` would still hold though. The type inference on `+` would have to be implemented using recursion too. In any case, homework should _encourage_ (not _prohibit_) fold expressions. This is **not** a good use case for template recursion. One would use recursion (e.g.) to unwind argument packs without a common `+` and/or common fold expressions in general. With a common `+` in existence, the homework requires something I would call bad practice (unnecessary recursion).

Comment: That↑ said, I’m not quite sure if I should delete the “answer” or make it unnecessarily recursive (which is not a good example to expose online)…

Comment: Another point is that the “simple” recursive solution (de)allocates O(_N_) vectors for _N_ arguments whereas a fold expression needs O(1) vector (de)allocations only… A way to fix that would be to pass around an output argument (vector reference) down the recursion stack. Which is still too much of a hassle.

Comment: I think the purpose of the exercise was to teach template recursion.